# Error con DB NULL en datagridview

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando pasar una columna de un datagridview a otra y necesito agregar mas días, pero al momento de hacer la conversion y mostrarlo en la otra tabla me aparece el siguiente error.

```
System.InvalidCastException' en mscorlib.dll

Información adicional: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
```

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
  DateTime?  ini;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {




                    dataGridView7.Rows.Add(DBNull.Value);
                    dataGridView7.Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Required Date"]);
                    ini = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Required Date"] );
                    ini = ini.Value.AddDays(75);
                    //MessageBox.Show( String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",ini));
                    dataGridView7.Rows.Add(String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ini));
                }
```

El error me lo marca en la siguiente linea

```
   ini = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Required Date"] );
```

No se como se pueda ingresar el mismo null que tiene en el datagridview original.
Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción es que compruebes si el dato en el DataRow es nulo antes de asignarselo a ini,algo así:

```
ini = (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Required Date"] != DBNull.Value ? 
           (DateTime?)Convert.ToDateTime((ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Required Date"].ToString()) 
          : null;
```

Esto en caso de que `RequiredDate`sea de tipo string, si es `DateTime`puedes hacer simplemente esto:

```
ini = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Required Date"] != DBNull.Value ?
         (DateTime?)ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Required Date"] 
         : null;
```

Aunque probablemente tu problema sea simplemente que te falta el cast a `DateTime?`, asi que esto debería funcionar tambien:

```
ini = (DateTime?)ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Required Date"];
```

**Edit** 
Parece ser que en esa columna aparecen letras en algunas filas. Tendrás entonces que comprobar si es posible convertirlo a `DateTime`:

```
DateTime tempDate;
if (DateTime.TryParse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Required Date"].ToString(), out tempDate))
{
    ini = tempDate;
}
else
{
    ini=null;
}
```

Comment: En los tres me aparece error.

Comment: Que contiene `ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Required Date"];`?

Comment: La mayoría son  fechas, pero los utlimos 10 registros son letras

Comment: Hombre,si son letras...como esperas que se conviertan a `DateTime`?

Comment: pero no hay forma de que se pasen como null ?

Comment: Mira la respuesta que acabo de editar

Comment: Me funcionó.Gracias